# How to use text of option to find value of the same

Tags: jquery

i have multiple select option which id name is test and has one option as B.

**$('#test').find('option[text="B"]').val();**

Here if i use this i am getting correct result i.e. value of this option.
But the problem is in jquery i don't have this B instead of that i have a variable which has value as B.Please tell me guys how can i use variable in the place of B in jquery.

i tried using this

var x=myVariable

**$('#test').find('option[text=x]').val();**

Thanks

Comment: Dhara's answer is correct. Keep in mind that you are never just writing "jQuery" code, you are writing *JavaScript* code. So you can take advantage of all the features of the JavaScript language. Any time you need a string value, as in your `.find()` call, you aren't limited to only a string constant. You can also use a variable, function call, or any expression that evaluates to a string - like the expression in Dhara's answer.

Comment: thanks @MichaelGeary for this help i will keep this things in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate variables like this, Try:

```
$('#test').find('option[text="'+x+'"]').val()
```

Comment: @ankeshmishra welcome :) mark it as answer if its helpful

Comment: ya i marked it but it says that you have to wait for atleast six minute